# set returning duplicates?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I'm pulling a list of URL's off a census website than putting them in a set to make sure I don't end up with duplicates, then exporting that list of non-duplicate URL's into a .csv file. However, My `set` continues to return duplicate values, which shouldn't be possible. Here's my code:

```
import bs4
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import csv

source_link = "https://www.census.gov/data/tables/2016/demo/popest/state-total.html"
s = requests.get(source_link)
usable_html = s.text
setupsoup = BeautifulSoup(usable_html, 'lxml')
silver = csv.writer(open("WGUCSV.csv", "r+"))
silver.writerow(["URL"])

for set(gold) in setupsoup.findAll('a', href=True):
    gold.add['href']
    print (gold)
    silver.writerow(gold)
```

As a bonus question, I also need a way to convert my resulting relative URL's into absolute URL's, preferably **before** sorting them into a non-duplicated list. I really thought adding them all to a `set` would filter out duplicates on it's own.

Comment: `for set(gold) in setupsoup.findAll('a', href=True):` is not even valid Python.

Comment: Did you mean `for gold in set(setupsoup.findAll('a', href=True)): ...`? or `for gold in setupsoup.findAll('a', href=True): gold = set(gold) ...`

Comment: My loop is now: for gold in set(setupsoup.findAll('a', href=True)):
 gold.add['href']
Which is still somehow returning duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add to a set, try

```
gold = set()
for x in setupsoup.findAll('a', href=True):
    gold.add(x)
```

or more simply

```
gold = set(setupsout.findAll('a', href=True))
```

Comment: I liked that setup a lot, that was easy for me to understand. I gave it a whirl, and my set STILL has duplicates. Check out the last bunch of URLS:

https://www.census.gov/quality/


https://www.census.gov/foia/

https://www.census.gov/privacy/

https://www.commerce.gov/

https://www.census.gov/quality/

https://www.census.gov/foia/

https://www.census.gov/privacy/

https://www.commerce.gov/


https://www.census.gov/quality/

https://www.census.gov/foia/

https://www.census.gov/privacy/

Comment: @houseofbacon This answer is on the right track, but you'd need to create a set on the hrefs, not the tags themselves.

Comment: @houseofbacon You need to look more carefully at the strings that are actually being added to the set. *Something* makes them different; `gold.add` will not add a string that already exists in the set.